# Loop one pair of cards for 100 times (deck of cards)

Tags: c++, string

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); //seeding rand with a starting value


    const string ranks[] = { "Ace",   "Two",  "Three", "Four", "Five",  "Six", "Seven",
                             "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",   "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    const string suits[] = {
        "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs"
    }; //array with 52 cards,4 suits each with 13 ranks(1 to King)

    int ranksindex = rand() % 13; //random index for drawing card 1
    int suitsindex = rand() % 4;

    int ranksindex2 = rand() % 13; // random index for drawing card 2
    int suitsindex2 = rand() % 4;

    string card1, card2;
    int    counter = 0;
    int    times   = 1000;
    int    i;

    for (i = 0; i < times; i++)
    {
        card1 = ranks[ranksindex] + " of "
                + suits[suitsindex]; // two random cards with the ranks and suits
        card2 = ranks[ranksindex2] + " of " + suits[suitsindex2];

        if (card1 == card2)
        {
            card2 = ranks[ranksindex] + " of "
                    + suits[suitsindex]; // to make the cards always different
        }

        cout << "The two cards drawn are : " << card1 << " and " << card2 << endl
             << endl; //display card the two cards drawn
    }
}
```

When i try to run the program , it doesnt finish the program ,its stuck there, what can i do to fix this?

Below is a picture of my output,it will run but it will not finish the whole program and display the counter

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PVaR.png   -picture of my output

Comment: You need to calculate `ranksindex `, `suitsindex ` etc inside loop

Comment: and you better use `std::uniform_int_distribution` rather than `rand`

Comment: Instead of working with string, use index between 0-51. only for display convert it to string.

Comment: `int ranksindex = rand() % 13;` calculates a value *once* and assigns it to `ranksindex`. Assigning to an `int` in c++ copies the immediate value, not the expression. Subsequent uses of `ranksindex` will always have the same value unless you assign a new one to it.

Comment: *update  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbArS.png  it will run but it will not finish the whole program and display the counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int ranksindex = rand() % 13; //random index for drawing card 1
int suitsindex = rand() % 4; 

int ranksindex2 = rand() % 13; // random index for drawing card 2
int suitsindex2 = rand() % 4;
```

The above code should be inside for loop.

For every turn you want to find out the random ranksIndex and suitsIndex. Right now, you were just finding it once and using it multiple times in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen after reformatting the code that the random values are been read outside the loop, therefore this code has to be moved inside the loop.

---

I believe that by getting 2 random numbers, the distribution of the outcome of selected cards will not be quite uniform.

Since You are looking for 1 card out of 52, then only 1 random value should be generated and then that value should be mapped to a card.

Here is an example:

```
constexpr auto card_ranks_count = 13;
constexpr auto card_suits_count = 4;

const int random_card = rand() % (card_ranks_count * card_suits_count);

const auto indexes = std::div(random_card, card_ranks_count);

const int ranksindex = indexes.rem;
const int suitsindex = indexes.quot;
```